# C# ComboBox Not Displaying DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

My application's `ComboBox`, instead of displaying the specified member, `"ProcName"`, is displaying the `ToString()` method results from that member's base class.  The `DataSource` is defined as

```
List<ProcTemplateRecord> procList = dbif.GetProcTemplateRecords();
```

...where `ProcTemplateRecord` is my defined class:

```
class BaseRecord
{
    public Int32 PrimaryKey;
    public String SysTime;
}
class ProcTemplateRecord : BaseRecord
{
    public String ProcName;
    public String Comments;
}
```

In my application code, this is how I connect the `ComboBox` to my list:

```
this.comboBox1.DataSource = procList;
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ProcName";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "PrimaryKey";
```

[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to convert those from fields to properties

Comment: @Plutonix How is that done?  This is new to me.

Comment: @Jim `public int PrimaryKey {get; set;}`  `public string ProcName {get; set;}`

Comment: @Plutonix That did the trick, thanks!  Feel free to post your answer, and I'll accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its subtle, but when typing:

```
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ProcName";
```

...notice the intellisense help: `Gets or sets the property name for ....`.  Binding works on *properties* not fields which is what all your members are.  Change them to properties and the binding should work:

```
class BaseRecord
{
    public Int32 PrimaryKey { get; set; }
    public String SysTime { get; set; }
}
class ProcTemplateRecord : BaseRecord
{
    public String ProcName { get; set; }
    public String Comments { get; set; }
}
```